# How to bind a host directory to docker container via docker CLI?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-cli

I'm trying to bind a host directory to a mssql docker container and have the following [bash] script:

```
#!/bin/sh

IMPORTDIR=$(cd $(dirname $0); pwd)
DATADIR=${DATADIR:-/tmp/db/}

set -xe

docker run --detach \
       -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" \
       -v ${DATADIR}:/mnt/db \
       -v ${IMPORTDIR}:/mnt/importing \
       -p 127.0.0.1:1433:1433 \
       --name mssql-db \
       mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
sleep 30

docker exec mssql-db /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P Passw0rd -Q "
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/mnt/db/mssql_db.bak'"
```

For which I receive the following error message when I run the script:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '\''/mnt/db/mssql_db.bak'\'''
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Server cd17fd41ce82, Line 2
Cannot open backup device '/mnt/db/mssql_db.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server cd17fd41ce82, Line 2
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.
```

When I log into the container I see that indeed the file, which is in the host directory, isn't present is in the container's directory.

The following is my setup info:

**Operating System:** Mac Os 10.13.6
**Docker Version:**
 [image: docker engine details screenshot]
**File perms (on the host):** -rw-r--r--@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this because by adding the real path to `/tmp` to the file sharing resource path in docker.
In my OS version (can't comment on the later versions), the `/tmp` is a symlink to it's real path `/private/tmp` once I added that to the *FILE SHARING* resources, it worked.
I had just recently upgraded to docker as this wasn't an issue I previously experienced pre-upgrade